# Opengl Model Matrix doesnt rotate around the origin after one rotation

Tags: c++, qt, opengl, c++11, rotation

I want to rotate my model Matix in x, y, and z direction, but it rotates in an unexpected way.
I use Qt.

```
QMatrix4x4 mMatrix;
mMatrix.setToIdentity();
mMatrix.rotate(yAngle, QVector3D(0, 1, 0));
mMatrix.rotate(zAngle, QVector3D(0, 0, 1));
mMatrix.translate(cube->getPosition());
```

After the first rotation the followed rotations rotate around the base of the new model Matrix, while I want the followed rotations to rotate around the origin.

I drew a little sketch so my problem might be clearer (black shows how it is right now, green is how i want it to be):
[image: sketch of the vector problemn]
The green arrow shows how i want it to be.

Comment: I need to transform the rotation Vector, dont I?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I got figured it out by myself, each object needs to have its own rotation Matrix / Quaterunion. 
A new rotation around the world origin ist done by creating a rotation matrix with the wanted rotation and right multiply the exiting rotation matrix of the object.

Answer (score 1):

I think you will get the desired result if you simply reverse the order of calls you make on the `QMatrix4x4` class. To combine the two rotations:

```
QMatrix4x4 mMatrix;
mMatrix.setToIdentity();
mMatrix.rotate(zAngle, QVector3D(0, 0, 1));
mMatrix.rotate(yAngle, QVector3D(0, 1, 0));
```

The documentation is kind of lacking, but from looking at the `QMatrix4x4` source code, I'm getting the impression that it applies matrix operations the way it's more or less standard with matrix libraries that are used for OpenGL, and the way the OpenGL fixed pipeline used to work.

This means that when you combine matrices, the new matrix is multiplied from the right. As a result, when the combined matrix is applied to vectors, the last specified sub-transformation is applied to the vectors first. Or putting it differently, you specify transformations in the reverse of the order you want them applied.

In your example, it you want to rotate around the y-axis first, then around the z-axis, you need to specify the z-rotation first, then the y-rotation.

Comment: I am sorry, this sketch is kind of misleading. I dont have the problem of a specified rotation. My Objects have a x,y and z degree which should describe how they are rotated around the world origin. If i apply the first rotation, the followed rotations are based on the new rotated matrix and dont rotate around the world origin.

Comment: Exactly, and you avoid that by reversing the order of applying the transformations.

Comment: No, that doesnt work. The rotation still rotates based on the rotated matrix, not on the base of the world origin

Answer (score 0):

Well, if you want the green arrow thing to happen, then it means that you want a rotation around the x-axis, 90 degrees in the negative direction (or 270 degrees in the positive direction).

To make things simple, think of it like this:

- Which of the axes there remains the same? `x`, right? Since `x` doesn't change, it looks like you're rotating around the x, and you are.
- Now, point your thumb towards the direction that positive x is directed at and casually close the rest of your fingers like a cylinder. The direction that those rest of your fingers curling at is the direction of the rotation.
- Since you want a rotation of 90 degrees in the opposite direction that those 4 fingers of yours are curling at, or 270 in the same direction... yeah.

`(1, 0, 0)` would be the direction vector pointing towards the positive `x`. While I don't know so much about the functions you're using, my guess is that the second call should be:

```
mMatrix.rotate(270, QVector3D(1, 0, 0));
```

Instead, or optionally `-90` if it supports negative values.

Comment: I have no Problem to reproduce the given State, i want the rotations be independent from each other rotation. The used methods are the given Qt methods of the given classes

Comment: Oh, I am so sorry that I've misunderstood your trouble, apologies. I am no expert, I had absolutely no information about this Qt thing until an hour ago; but I have spent some time looking through their project website just now, and I have this one simple guess: **Could you try** changing your rotations into the form `mMatrix.rotate( angle, mMatrix.map( QVector3D( 0, 0, 1 ) ) );` and then tell me if it works?

Comment: I have added it, and it doesnt seem to work as expected. Since i am stuck in this Problem since hours i found out that quaternions seem to be the better way, but these are also rotated based on the changed model matrix. I dont understand what this map method does but i assume it returns the coords of the vector thats equal to an axis in the world system. I now try to combine quaternions with the use of the map method, but this is still groping in the dark for me.